# Trouble exporting JSON to Mongo with pymongo

Tags: json, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

```
client = MongoClient(conn)
db = client.get_default_database()

json_file = {'test_1':1, 'test_2':2}
db.insert_one(json_file)
```

generates:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insert_many' method on a 'Database' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

Checking my version of pymongo:

```
$ pip freeze | grep pymongo
$ pymongo==3.2.2
```

Which I think means that the `insert_one` and `insert_many` methods should be available (post `pymongo 3.0`, right?). More confusingly, when I call `dir(db)` I don't see any references to any `insert` methods at all.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's so hard to debug a cyrptic error message *"**'Collection'** object is not callable. If you meant to call the 'insert_many' method on a **'Database'** object"*. Welcome to `pymongo`. Next time, give the documentation ( and the error messsges ) a little more than just a glance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `db` refers to your database, you need to access a [collection object](https://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html) with a dot notation:

```
db.col.insert_one(json_file)
```

or in a dictionary-like style:

```
db["col"].insert_one(json_file)
```

where `col` is the name of your collection.